# How to convert TZ-format string with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time, format

Here is my original dataframe:

```py
        creationDate

0       2022-06-02T12:41:47.498Z
1       2022-06-02T12:45:13.994Z
2       2022-06-02T12:58:57.684Z
3       2022-06-02T13:24:59.379Z
4       2022-06-02T13:29:57.304Z
```

I want to transform it this way:

```py
        creationDate

0       2022-06-02
1       2022-06-02
2       2022-06-02
3       2022-06-02
4       2022-06-02
```

Here is what I do:

```py
df["creationDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["creationDate"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Or:

```py
df["creationDate"] = df["creationDate"].apply(lambda x: x[:10])
```

Which is working.

But, I feel like there is another easier way.

How would you do it?

Comment: try df["creationDate"] = df["creationDate"].dt.date

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sticking with the first option. For the second option, you can use

```
df["creationDate"].str[:10]
```

instead. I don't think there are any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is the right way for me, however you can use:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['creationDate']).dt.date
0    2022-06-02
1    2022-06-02
2    2022-06-02
3    2022-06-02
4    2022-06-02
Name: creationDate, dtype: object  # <- not a datetime64 but a string
```

If you want to keep the column as DatetimeIndex, use:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['creationDate']).dt.tz_localize(None).dt.normalize()
0   2022-06-02
1   2022-06-02
2   2022-06-02
3   2022-06-02
4   2022-06-02
Name: creationDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]  # <- now you have a real datetime
```

As you have iso format date, you have the timezone so remove it (`localize`) then reset the time part (`normalize`).